# Ruby: Changing an array of items into links in an ERB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of strings that I want to interpolate into links within an erb file.
How would I approach this syntactically?

Currently, I have the following

```
    <% names.each do |name| %>
<b>
    <%=name%>
</b>
<%end%>

<% navigation=["home","about us","store","contact","blog"] %>
<%navigation.each do |navitem| %>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href= <%=/#{navitem}/%>".html">
        <%=navitem%>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <%end%>
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you've got?

Comment: @VladtheImpala `<a href= <%=/#{navitem}/%>".html">` will return nothing because `<%=/#{navitem}/%>` is a regexp.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
<a href= <%=/#{navitem}/%>".html">
```

to

```
<a href="<%= navitem %>.html">
```